# Problem execute procedure in oracle ORA-06550

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I try to execute a package in oracle that it works when call him with software, but in sql developer no

show me the following error:

> ORA-06550: Line 2 column 11
> PLS-00103 Encountered the symbol "package name" when expection one the following
> := . ( @ % ; was substituted form "package name" to continue.
> 06550. 000000 - "line%s column %s:\n%s"
> *Cause: Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
> *Action
> Vendor code 6550 Error at Line:1
> the line 11 start of name package

```
begin
  execute packageName.procedureName(parameter1,parameter2,parameter3,...);
end
```

Comment: There is no `execute` keyword in the [PL/SQL language](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/book-index.html), except as part of `execute immediate`. What manual are you getting your syntax from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `EXECUTE`. It is used when you want to run a procedure at SQL*Plus prompt. In PL/SQL, you don't use it.

Code that *should* work is:

```
begin
   packageName.procedureName(parameter1,parameter2,parameter3,...);
end;
/
```

Comment: I'm use  oracle sql developer, but I remove execute, begin and end and not work

Comment: So what? Remove EXECUTE.

Comment: not works, in footer show the message "no SQL statement entered"

Comment: I edited the answer and posted code you should be using. I told you to remove EXECUTE, literally that word. not the entire line.

Comment: What happened when you did it? Could you post a screenshot (if you think it'll be more descriptive)?

Comment: I think the another problem is a cache. it works now. thanks

Comment: You're welcome; I'm glad you made it work.